# Baking rigid body transformations

Tags: objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have created a simulation using rigid bodies to create a nice pile of "things" that will be fairly realistic. Now I would like to save or bake these new positions and rotations from selected frame into object data. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can press **Bake To Keyframes** button in Rigid Body Tools panel.

[image]